# Avoid auto filling of missing values in pd.MltiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I try to read an Excel file with those data. 
The first 2 columns are index columns. 
In the third line, the second index is missing.

```
              2017   2018
Airbus          10      8
Airbus  A320     2      7
Airbus           4     10
Airbus  A320     5      1
```

I read the Excel file like this :

```
df = pd.read_excel(
    "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.xlsx",
    sheet_name = 'Feuil1',
    index_col = [0,1],
    header = [0]
    )
```

But the second index of my third line became A320 :

```
              2017   2018
Airbus          10      8
Airbus  A320     2      7
Airbus  A320     4     10
Airbus  A320     5      1
```

I whould like the empty indexes to stay empty or at least to fill empty indexes with the value of my choice. How can I do that ?

Comment: `df = pd.read_excel(
    "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.xlsx",
    sheet_name = 'Feuil1',
    index_col = [0],
    header = [0]
    ) `?

Comment: I can read the column with A320 as a serie then do fillna and then convert that serie to an index but I wonder if there is a better and cleaner way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to solve this,

set index after reading your data will solve your problem,

```
print (df.set_index(df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')].values.tolist()))
```

Output:

```
                       2017  2018
Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1            
Airbus     NaN           10     8
           A320           2     7
           NaN            4    10
           A320           5     1
```